# Set max value based on another input

Tags: javascript, html, input, attributes, max

I need to set a max value of an input based on the value of another input.

I will have two inputs, input x and input y, a user inputs a value in each but the value for y can be no more than 80% of the value of x, so I want a max value on input y so you can't go over 80% of input x.

so if someone puts 100 in input x and tries to put 90 in input y, input y would change to be 80 because that would be the max.

I intend to use javascript and HTML to achieve this.

Comment: nice idea. do you have some code to show?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't, I've looked around on this all day to find a starting point and I can't find anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest monitoring the input using the `onchange` event of both fields and limiting the value using `Math.min(...)`

Here is a snippet:

```js
var elX = document.getElementById("X");
var elY = document.getElementById("Y");

function limit() {
 elY.value=Math.min(Math.round(elX.value*.8),elY.value);
}

elX.onchange=limit;
elY.onchange=limit;
```

```html
<input type="number" id="X" value="0"><br>
<input type="number" id="Y" value="0">
```

Comment: Oh, I don't suppose there would be a way of doing this if the input type were text instead of number, but the value was an integer?

Comment: You can use `type="text"`, too, as long as you only enter numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple solution using JQuery and 2 simple input fields. It pretty much does what you want -> [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7xeu3oom/)

Related HTML:

```
<input type="number"id="x">  
<input type="number" id="y">
```

Related JS:

```
(function(){
$("#y").on("change", function(e){
    var x = $("#x").val()
  if($(this).val() > (x*80)/100){
    $(this).val(((x*80)/100));
    alert("field Y cannot excede 80% of field X")
  }
})
}())
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right:

The input is like something this:

```
<input type="number" id="Y" max="numberHere">
```

You can do it **like** this:

```
var temp = document.getElementById("Y");
var maxValue = document.getElementById("X").value * 0.8;
temp.setAttribute("max",maxValue); // set a new value;
```

Comment: This is the principle, and this example does work when using those little arrows to set the number, but I need it to respond to a user physically typing something like "100" and then it would change to the max value

Comment: The "onchange" or "oninput" didn't rise when the user set the number typing?

Comment: Nothing happened when typed, the max was apparent when adjusting the value via the arrows

Comment: if you bind the oninput, and in that function you set the new max, and check if the actual value is grater than the new max, then you set it to the new max